# Зачем просить автора вносить изменения в вопрос в очереди проверок?

Tags: дефект, очередь-проверок

Среди причин удаления ответов есть "Это не ответ, а комментарий к другому сообщению". Текст причины отличается в зависимости от того, написан ответ автором вопроса или другим человеком. Так выглядит текст, если ответ дал автор вопроса:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что мы говорим автору вопроса, что он должен написать комментарий к вопросу, чтобы попросить автора вопроса (самого себя) внести в него изменения? Это что-то странное.

---

**Обновление**

Похоже, что текст причины зависит как от репутации, так и от авторства вопроса. Вот несколько случаев, не на все сохранились ссылки, но самые важные здесь последние.

1. Репутация 1, автор вопроса ≠ автор ответа.

   > В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.
2. Репутация 65, автор вопроса ≠ автор ответа.

   > Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.
3. Репутация 35, автор вопроса = автор ответа.

   > [Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/463787).
4. Репутация 1, автор вопроса = автор ответа.

   > [Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/463817)

**Итог:** если автор ответа не является автором вопроса, то текст причины зависит от репутации автора ответа. Если автор ответа является автором вопроса, то текст причины будет одинаковый независимо от его репутации.

В принципе, это согласуется с комментарием Qwertiy:

> Ну первое автору показываться не должно - он всегда может комментировать.

Но ведь и второе автору показываться не должно! Глупо предлагать пользователю предложить самому себе внести правку.

Comment: "написан ответ автором вопроса или другим человеком" уверены?

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, Пока только такая зависимость обнаружена. Но я ещё понаблюдаю за репутацией ответивших и дополню вопрос.

Comment: Ну ссылки на проверки где?

Answer (score 4):

> Текст причины отличается в зависимости от того, написан ответ автором вопроса или другим человеком

Насколько я могу судить, то там всё не так. Вариантов всего два:

1. Когда у участника мало репутации, то:

   > В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша репутация достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению; на данный момент, пожалуйста, внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора.
2. Если достаточно, то:

   > Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению.

И, как я понимаю, если репутации хватает, то независимо от авторства подсовывается второй вариант. В оригинале там тоже "clarification from an author". Так что, если и менять, то нужно просить на MSE, чтоб они разный текст подставляли в зависимости от авторства.

Comment: Ну первое автору показываться не должно - он всегда может комментировать.